# I too have knocked off a component from the underside of my Pi 4 board. HELP

Tags: pi-4, hardware, boot-issues

[image]**I too have knocked off a component from the underside of my Pi 4 board, a result of a poorly designed case. I could use help to identify the component. As I am dyslexic reading a schematic sends me around the block a few times. Just looking at the board I am assuming that the part is a resistor and having to do with the Wi-Fi circuit.  Attached are pics of the problem.  Thanks for any help from anyone.
----------**

Answer (score 2):

There are no schematics published for the Raspberry Pi. Only reduced schematics are available, which show connectors and parts of the power distribution circuit. You won't find that resistor in there.

From the looks of it this could be a pull-up / pull-down of some sort. If I had to do this without any schematic, I would solder a 100 kOhm resistor and see if the board boots up. If not, I would then try 10 kOhm, 1 kOhm and finally 100 Ohm, and if none of them would work, I'd get a new board.

Comment: The four little guys look like twin brothers from the same family, perhaps all 4k7 or 10k. I would do the following for fun: (1) desolder one the three remaining, and use a multimeter to check the value, which is very likely 4k7 or 10k. (2) put back two through hole 4k7/10k resistors (yes, no need SMD), and see if you have luck.

Comment: @tlfong01 Could be the same (especially the first 3 from the left), but not necessarily. Measuring just one out of four is in no way a guarantee that the remaining three have the same value.

Comment: Ha, talk is cheap, let us measure it. My cheapy multi-meter says ***all four brothers are 1k8***, very likely I2C pullups. Green Fields - Brothers Four 3,802,575 views
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46o1joHp7t0